# Is it possible (and safe) to adapt a 4-prong dryer outlet to a NEMA 6-20?

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

I'm considering an appliance that is 240V 16A 3500 Watt with a NEMA 6-20P plug. Is it possible and safe to create an adapter for this so that it can be plugged into a standard 4-prong 14-30R dryer outlet? The adapter would be a typical 4-prong dryer cord with a NEMA 6-20R receptacle.

Would this be possible? NEMA 14 is hot/hot/neutral/ground. Could this be wired to a 6-20 receptacle that is hot/hot/ground? What is done with the neutral? If possible, would it be unsafe because of the 30A circuit and 20A receptacle (or other reasons)?

EDIT:
To add some more info, the appliance is an an Avantco IC3500 induction cooktop. It is ETL listed and the label on the bottom states that it complies with UL Std 197, which I cannot find details on with respect to amperage.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/L14-30P-6-20R-Power-Cord-Adapter/dp/B004XWAKUQ  -- These are available commercially

Comment: @ChrisCudmore How is it safe to plug an adapter rated at 20A into a 30A receptacle if not protected by a 20A CB?

Comment: Those adapters are home made and not UL listed. If I had to I could make one of those up in about 10 minutes from stock I have on the truck.

Comment: http://www.rackmountpdu.com/products/699-1-foot-l14-30p-to-6-1520r-power-cord.aspx says UL listed, RoHS certified, CSA approved...what gives?

Comment: Unfortunately, the 14-30 outlet is not locking (L14-30).

Comment: @ Mazura, the one you linked is NOT the same as the one in the Amazon link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is it depends on the appliance. As long as the appliance does not expressly forbid using it on a 30A circuit you should be fine. You'll be able to change the plug and put on a 14-30P plug, just ignore the silver terminal (neutral).

Comment: I would err on the side of the manual expressively permitting 30A service or field modifications to the cord. Just because the manual doesn't say you can't, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: I contacted the manufacturer who said, "This has 14.5-16.8 amps so a 30 amp circuit would be fine."

Comment: Still, be careful about the device failing and drawing too much current, which could cause a fire.

Comment: Greg, can you please explain how this would be possible before the breaker trips? Also, how can it draw too much current (outside of a dead short of course)?

Comment: If you're using a device that's rated at 20A, on a 30A circuit, and the catches fire between 20A and 30A. Not saying it's likely.

Comment: My point is how would it catch fire? How is it any different than plugging a 1A radio into a 20A circuit? What if the radio catches fire between 1 and 20 amps? Get my point?

Comment: @SpeedyPetey That "1A radio" may only draw 1 ampere, but it's designed to carry the full load of the circuit it's connected to (20 amperes).  A device with a NEMA 6-20 plug, is not likely designed to handle 30 amperes.  The wiring in the device *could* theoretically catch fire, before the breaker tripped.

Comment: @tester101, what??? That makes absolutely no sense. The plugged in load DOES NOT carry the full current of the circuit. I totally disagree with you last comment and stand by what I wrote almost a year ago. There is no added risk of fire doing what the OP suggests.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey There *could* be a problem, if the device develops a fault. That's part of the purpose of having different plug configurations.

Comment: When a device is fitted with a plug it means: 1) During normal operation, the device will not draw more current than the circuit rating. 2) During a fault, the device can handle the full load of the circuit for long enough for the circuit to open.

Comment: @Tester101, sorry, I disagree with you here. The circuit overcurrent protection is to protect the circuit conductors, NOT the attached load.
Again, in the OPs example (a 16A load with a 20A plug), it is no different, actually even less of a difference, than a 1A radio with a 15A plug plugged into a 20A receptacle/circuit.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey I argee that the circuit overcurrent protection is there to protect the circuit conductors. However, the factory attached plug on a device, is part of that devices UL listing.  If the device has a 20 amp plug, that means it has been UL tested on a 20 ampere circuit. If you plug a 20 ampere device into a 30 ampere circuit, you're operating that device outside of the UL listing. Otherwise, what's the point of having different plugs at all?

Answer (score 0):

You could wire a 20 amp breaker into the adapter. Something along [these lines](http://www.delcity.net/store/Thermal-Push-Button-Circuit-Breakers/p_539615.h_539678.t_1.r_IF1003?mkwid=scHWRqYx9&crid=38094426869&mp_kw=&mp_mt=&gclid=Cj0KEQjwmNuuBRDTu5rDjr2kxJsBEiQAWlm6UjLC3gRJGzK8jDu81t156PhWF-JXQJG-y6AzWW-_aF8aAsa88P8HAQ) would be perfect. Easy to reset as well.

Comment: Why is this down voted? Connecting an appliance that is meant to be plugged in to a 15 or 20 Amp circuit in to a 30 Amp circuit can be a hazard, and adding a fuse is the right thing to do. Since this device won't be left unattended, it's probably not worth it, but in general the fuse should be added when doing something like this.

Comment: A comment for a down vote should require a comment rather than just have it suggested.  I would consider a down vote to this because it would likely be safer and/or easier to simply replace the outlet and circuit breaker to fit the intended use, and because it is not a complete answer.  I'd reserve a down vote for answers that are clearly wrong, unsafe, off topic, and/or not an actual answer.  This may be better placed as a comment than as an answer.