# Is it possible to adapt a NEMA 14-50R to a NEMA 6-20P or NEMA 6-30P appliance?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, 240v, 120-240v

In a Canadian residential kitchen, in a house built in the late 1970's, there is a NEMA 14-50R, on a 30 Amp breaker.

Currently a standard oven/range combo is plugged into this receptacle. I would like to replace it with a commercial induction range, e.g. [BRIC 3000](http://www.hubert.ca/38358/Equipex-Heavy-Duty-Induction-Range-13-15-Amps.html) or [BRIC 3600](http://www.hubert.ca/56635/Equipex-Heavy-Duty-Induction-Range-15-18-Amps.html), that has either a NEMA 6-20P or NEMA L6-30P.

While there seems to be [commercially made adaptors for some configurations](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/46826/is-it-possible-and-safe-to-adapt-a-4-prong-dryer-outlet-to-a-nema-6-20), I can't see anything for this specific setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing easier.  You're already on a 30A breaker, just change the receptacle to L6-30R.

Don't even bother with an adapter cable.

Just cap off the neutral inside the junction box, you won't need it.

However the breaker must match the receptacle.  If you change to a NEMA 6-20R receptacle, you'd need to change the breaker to 20A.

Comment: I'll accept your answer, as it's generally the most correct one. I didn't include an extra constraint in my question; I have to leave the receptacle alone in the short term, as the range needs to stay there and working.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping to combine it with correcting a pre-existing illegal condition: a 50A receptacle on a 30A breaker.  While technically illegal, it seems prudent as long as you're in control of the situation.  The problem is those non-L receptacles and plugs are not made for daily plug and unplug - the L twist-lock connectors are.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I have found is to start with a NEMA 14-50P to NEMA L14-30R adapter cord, and then add a NEMA L14-30P to NEMA L6-30R adapter cord (variants of that are also available with a NEMA 6-20R).

Neither of these seem to be available online in Canada, but they can be ordered from US distributors.

The specific parts I have found are:

- "Coleman Wire / Southwire" [Range plug to L14-30R connector adapter cord set](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/322190163272). CatNo 18640008, UPC 029892050108.
- "Iron Box" [NEMA L14-30P to L6-30R Power Cord Plug Adapter](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/110772984435). PartNo BX-4489-01.

It seems the hard thing is the NEMA 14-50, stuff for NEMA L14-30 seems much more widely available.